# Remove white space left and right side in masterpage

Tags: asp.net, html, css, webforms

I use:

1. Visual Studio 2010
2. ASP.net (Webforms)

I want to remove the white space like shown on this picture:
The white space is visible on both the left and right side of the masterpage.

[image: a busy cat]

This is how the site should look like - The whole page's width is being used:

[image: a busy cat]

I've already tried to set the "body" width to 100%, but that didn't help.
How do I solve my problem?

Comment: Solved!

I had to set the body's "margin-left" to "0px".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
body{margin:0;padding:0;}
```